# MCMC inside Expectation Maximization

Tags: simulation, markov-chain-montecarlo, conditional-expectation, expectation-maximization

I wish to optimize the following likelihood function for parameter $\Theta$:

$$p(D|\Theta)=\int_X\int_Y p(x, y, D|\Theta)dydx$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are latent variables and only $D$ is observed. I would like to use the Expectation-Maximization (EM) algorithm. If I understand it correctly, the E-step of the algorithm would be:

$$Q(\Theta|\Theta^{(t)})=\mathbb E_{X, Y|D,\Theta^{(t)}}[\log(p(X, Y, D|\Theta))]$$

However, I can only get samples from $p(X, Y|D,\Theta^{(t)})$ using Markov Chain Monte Carlo. So, I did the following:

$$Q(\Theta|\Theta^{(t)})=\mathbb E_{X, Y|D,\Theta^{(t)}}[\log(p(X, Y|D,\Theta))]+\log(p(D|\Theta))$$

Since $D$ is observed, I can calculate $\log(p(D|\Theta))$ from the data. Now here's my question: is it correct? And would you recommend any other way to do it or any other algorithm to use here?

Comment: Note: I corrected some $\Theta^{(t)}$ into $\Theta$ in the E-step.

Comment: Sounds like a case where you might apply variational inference

Comment: The decomposition you want to do might be this: $Q(\Theta|\Theta^{(t)})=\mathbb E_{X, Y|D,\Theta^{(t)}}[\log(p(D|, X, Y,\Theta)) + \log(p(X,Y|\Theta))]$, since in most cases we know the likelihood model D | X, Y and the prior for X, Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proposal is apparently negating the point in running an EM algorithm since, were $p(D|\theta)$ available in an analytic form, the completion by the latent variables would not be necessary since a numerical maximisation algorithm could be called upon.

Even within the EM algorithm framework the decomposition does not help since 
$$\log p(x,y|D,\theta) + \log p(D|\theta) = \log p(x,y,D|\theta)$$
does not modify the M-step.

When running a Monte Carlo EM (MCEM) version, the conditional expectation is replaced with
$$\frac{1}{T} \sum_{\iota=1}^T \log p(x_\iota,y_\iota,D|\theta)\qquad (x_\iota,y_\iota)\sim p(x,y|D,\theta^{(t)})$$
where the decomposition is not useful either.